# MATLAB plot: strange horizontal lines

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to produce a plot of theta vs. omega (theta on the x-axis, omega on the y-axis) and the plot I am generating looks ok except for stray horizontal lines that seem to span from -pi to pi. Does anyone know what causes this to happen, or how to remove them?

[image: phase-space]

Thanks

Comment: Well they will be coming whatever you are plotting, but without seeing any code it is not possible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Show some code or sample data if you really want help. Also try `plot(theta,omega,'.')` ... this will show you if you have just a few stray points on the border of your domain or if the lines are fully defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you provide your code, we won't be able to provide the good answer. These methods might help, though:

- If there are sufficient points on the plot, and they are dense in the plot and less dense on the unwanted lines, you can try to insert `'bx'` into `plot`, so the graph would consist of only blue crosses that would possibly make lines invisible retaining the remaining graph.
- You can convert all the unwanted points in the matrices to NaN either manually or by adding some command like `A(A>2)=NaN`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. The code is going to be assessed, so I didn't want to post it, but this rectified the problem as far as plotting. The data was 100% correct, so we were having difficulty figuring out why matlab was connecting the points that way, but this cleans it up perfectly.