# Strange lines when plotting contour lines using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, line, matlab-figure, contourf

I get strange lines when trying to save a plot with contour lines (see attached pic). How do I get rid of these straight lines? there are also some before saving depending on my set xlim or contour levels. I have a feeling there might be a setting I can turn on/off to remove this but not sure what it is...

[image: attached image]

code:

% all matrices are 500x93;

```
% Create axes
axes('Parent',gcf,...
    'Position',[0.130555555555556 0.0685483870967742 0.791666666666667 0.157258064516129]);

contourf(xi_S(1:500,1:93).*Mask_bin_S(1:500,1:93),yi_S(1:500,1:93).*Mask_bin_S(1:500,1:93),...
    zi_S(1:500,1:93).*Mask_bin_S(1:500,1:93),...
    15,'LineStyle','none','Clipping','on')

hold on

contour(xi_S(1:500,1:93).*Mask_bin_S,yi_S(1:500,1:93).*Mask_bin_S,zi_S(1:500,1:93).*Mask_bin_S,...
    37.8:0.2:38.6,'k','ShowText','On','Clipping','on') 
% set contours to be certain intervals, not same as contourf

colormap(gca,flipud(cbrewer('div', 'RdYlBu', 100))); % colormap set
colorbar('peer',gca,'Position',...
    [0.9320074833252 0.0698924731182796 0.0193814055636889 0.387096774193549]);
set(gca,'ydir','reverse','FontSize',16,...
    'XTickLabel',['';'';'';'';'';'';'';'';'';'';'';'';'';''],...
    'XTick',[735761 735762 735763 735764 735765 735766 735767 735768 735769 735770 735771 735772 735773 735774]);
% xlabel('time [days]');
ylabel('axis');
ylim([100 1000])
caxis([37.8 38.7])
xlim([7.357619044019791e+05 7.3577325e+05]);

fname = 'saving/location/'
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','centimeters','PaperPosition',[0 0 30 20])
print('-dpng', 'text.png, -r300');
saveas(gcf,fullfile(fname,['nameoffile']), 'png') %Save figure
```

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: Which Matlab version are you using?

Comment: Does the problem occur with this particular contour or with every contour you plot and save?

Comment: MATLAB 2014b, and it happens with every plot. At the moment I am just changing the size of the figure window until the lines disappear and then manually saving but this is not ideal..and difficult sometimes

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but failed. Also, I can not clearly distinguish between your contours lines and strange lines. So, could you pls run this script `Z=peaks(20); contourf(Z,10)  fname='myContourImage'; 
saveas(gcf,fullfile(fname),'png')` and send me a link to output contour plot (image file)?

Comment: The above script produces [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CSb5R.png) contour with no strange line when I try. I used the same Matlab version as yours.

Comment: Orions, your code worked fine but when I removed the set and print lines for my data so that I just had fname=...., and saveas.... it still produced strange lines with my date. Maybe it's related to the variability of the data? peaks may be a lot simpler

Comment: May be, in that case, I would need to know the functions definitions of `xi_S`, `Mask_bin_S` and other functions you are using in your code.

Comment: they are simply 2D matrices of the same size. xi_S is actual data which varies between 37.8 to around 38.6. Mask_bin_S is a matrix of ones and zeros used to mask (remove) some of the data from view when plotting. The data for xi_S have been extrapolated/interpolated using objective mapping using scattered data points as input (objmap.m). The same effect happens with a number of plots using other data objectively mapped too..

Comment: Can you provide me some data / code so that I can reproduce the issue (strange lines)?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29994318/2873538) might help you.